# Gnome Terminal, take the whole ghost suggestion?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Version 3.42.2 for GNOME 41. If I type a few letters, it shows a ghost suggestion. How can I take this suggestion and type the whole thing? I have tried some modifier + tab, but none of them worked.

For example, if I type `s`, ghosting "sudo intel_gpu_top" appears, but how can I take the whole "sudo intel_gpu_top" suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Try hitting the ***END*** key; works for me with **fish** shell.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that right arrow also works.